# error related to different arguments and type

Tags: oracle

this is the error:Error(277,3): PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'MANUFACTURING_OUTPUT'

```
UPDATE T1
SET UKURS   = CAST(1 /CAST(v_UKURS AS Number(32,5))AS Number(32,2))
WHERE FCURR = 'EUR'
AND TCURR   = 'INR';
PURCHASING_OUTPUT() ;
MANUFACTURING_OUTPUT();
```

as i m migrating my code from sql srver to oracle.

Comment: The error is pretty straightforward it is saying that you are calling a procedure/function without passing all the parameters. On your case `MANUFACTURING_OUTPUT();` so add this function definition on yoyr question or, if you find out pass the needed parameter.

Comment: What is the specification (i.e. the `create or replace procedure manufacturing_output ... is` bit) of the manufacturing_output procedure? Please update your question to include it.

Comment: when query:   desc manufacturing_output; runs output  is:                                                                                                     Argument Name Type       In/Out Default 
------------- ---------- ------ ------- 
CV_1          REF CURSOR OUT    unknown

Comment: these are the procedure specifications.:create or replace PROCEDURE           "MANUFACTURING_OUTPUT" (
    cv_1 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR )
AS
    
  v_intFlag2        NUMBER(10,0);
  v_length2         NUMBER(10,0);
  v_activitycolumn  VARCHAR2(255);
  v_priceunitcolumn VARCHAR2(255);
  v_activityvalue   VARCHAR2(255);
  v_priceunitvalue  VARCHAR2(255);
  v_material        VARCHAR2(255);
  v_plant           VARCHAR2(255);

   v_intFlag    NUMBER(10,0);
  v_intOldFlag NUMBER(10,0);
  v_counter    NUMBER(10,0);

BEGIN

Comment: @Boneist please help

Comment: Isn't it clear, both from the error message and the procedure spec? You have a procedure that has an out parameter, but you're calling it without passing any parameters in. You need to create a variable that's a sys_refcursor (since that's the datatype of the out parameter in your procedure) and use that when calling the procedure.

Comment: In fact, I would highly recommend you read up on PL/SQL. [The documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/subprograms.htm) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

To find out how many and what type of parameters you need to pass the function/procedure:

```
DESC MANUFACTURING_OUTPUT;
```

You will get something like this:

```
FUNCTION MANUFACTURING_OUTPUT RETURNS NUMBER
Argument Name                    Type                 IN/OUT   
-------------------------------- -------------------- -------- 
SITE_ID                          NUMBER               IN   
PRODUCT_ID                       NUMBER               IN
LOCATION                         VARCHAR              IN
```

Pass it the correct number and type of parameters.

Comment: when query:   desc manufacturing_output; runs output  is:                                                                                                                               Argument Name Type       In/Out Default 
                   ------------- ---------- ------ ------- 
              CV_1          REF CURSOR OUT    unknown

Comment: You left off the first line.